# Timezone Changes won't apply on Debian-based System

Tags: raspberry-pi, timezone, debian, raspbian

I'm trying to apply the timezone Europe/Berlin on a Raspberry PI running the Debian-based Raspbian.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

returns

```
Current default time zone: 'Europe/Berlin'
Local time is now:      Sun Jun 25 20:26:51 CEST 2017.
Universal Time is now:  Sun Jun 25 18:26:51 UTC 2017.
```

but

`sudo date`

still returns the British Summer Time (BST) instead of the Europe/Berlin Central European Summer Time (CEST)

`Sun Jun 25 19:26:55 BST 2017`

Answer (score -1):

> If there is internet connection available follow the steps to set the
>   date/time:
>
> 1. sudo raspi-config
> 2. Internationalization options
> 3. Change Time Zone
> 4. Select geographical area
> 5. Select city or region.
> 6. Reboot your pi.

This way, you will have accurate time. Need not set the date again for every boot.